# CRC table algorithm in C, width limitation

Tags: c, algorithm, crc

I found an easy to use implementation of CRC algorithms [here](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crctester.c). It includes table based and bit-wise algorithms. The code seems to work fine but there is an important limitation of table based algorithms. This is the relevant code:

```
unsigned long reflect (unsigned long crc, int bitnum) {
    unsigned long i, j=1, crcout=0;

    for (i=(unsigned long)1<<(bitnum-1); i; i>>=1) {
        if (crc & i) crcout|=j;
        j<<= 1;
    }
    return (crcout);
}

void generate_crc_table() {
    // make CRC lookup table used by table algorithms

    int i, j;
    unsigned long bit, crc;

    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        crc=(unsigned long)i;
        if (refin) crc=reflect(crc, 8);
        crc<<= order-8;

        for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
            bit = crc & crchighbit;
            crc<<= 1;
            if (bit) crc^= polynom;
        }           

        if (refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);
        crc&= crcmask;
        crctab[i]= crc;
    }
}  

unsigned long crctablefast (unsigned char* p, unsigned long len) {

    // fast lookup table algorithm without augmented zero bytes, e.g. used in pkzip.
    // only usable with polynom orders of 8, 16, 24 or 32.

    unsigned long crc = crcinit_direct;

    if (refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);

    if (!refin) while (len--) crc = (crc << 8) ^ crctab[ ((crc >> (order-8)) & 0xff) ^ *p++];
    else while (len--) crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctab[ (crc & 0xff) ^ *p++];

    if (refout^refin) crc = reflect(crc, order);
    crc^= crcxor;
    crc&= crcmask;

    return(crc);
}
```

Please note code comments for table functions say:

> only usable with polynom orders of 8, 16, 24 or 32.

Are table based algorithms generally limited to widths that are multiples of eight (especially table algorithms that use 16 and 32 bit tables)?

Is it possible to implement a table based CRC algorithm that accepts *any* CRC widths (not only multiples of 8)? How?

Comment: Not my downvote. But the question should be self contained, i.e. any code relevant to the question should be in the question itself. The answer to your question is, "Yes, you can use a generator polynomial of any order with a table based CRC algorithm." But in order to explain the comment you quoted, the code needs to be in the question.

Comment: Certainly code can be written to handle CRC's at values other than multiples of 8.  8 is just simpler.  The post's goal is wide ranging, suggest narrowing.

Comment: @chux: narrowing? How?

Comment: Of course its possible for any width, but the code would be alot more complex and slower to run. Its like asking can you do signed math that overflows at 13 bits. Of course you can, but you are going to have to do a lot of work yourself to make it happen.

Comment: @Secto Kia: Well currently I use bit-wise algorithm for uncommon widths which probably is worst case. Any help or example how to implement it?

Comment: The only limitation in the CRC code itself is the shift by `order-8`. That assumes that `order >= 8`. There is however the issue of the `reflect` function. I assume that function contains code that requires multiples of 8. If you don't need to `reflect` the input and output, the multiply of 8 limitation should go away.

Comment: @user3386109: Added reflect code. Seems to have no such limitation.

Comment: Yup, the reflect code is bitwise. So I see no reason for that comment. The only limitation in that code is `order` must be `>= 8`. So I would choose a generator polynomial with 9 bits, and then compare outputs from your bitwise code, and this table-based code. Of course, you should start by making sure your code agrees with this code for 8,16,24, and 32 bits. You're going to need to get the reflections sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement table-based CRCs for any width polynomial. See the output of [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) for example of table-based implementations for, for example, 5-bit, 13-bit, and 31-bit CRCs.

There is nothing tricky about this.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting code of yours. Maybe I skipped that when browsing the files... but why does the code include a bit-wise function? Is there anything the bit-wise function can do what the table functions can't? Or is it for testing only?

Comment: Yes. You need the bit-wise function to build the tables! Also if you want to compute the CRC on a number of bits that are not a multiple of eight, then you can adapt the bit-wise function to do that. Lastly, in an embedded system, the compactness of the CRC function may be more important than the speed.

Comment: With "multiple of eight" you mean the data width, not the checksum width, right?

Comment: I tried to use your code. Getting a seg fault. I added an issue to github... are you active there?

Comment: Yes. You can't use a literal string.